# How to find the allocation address of inherited classes

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have tries to create a couple of generic `create`/`delete` functions which is used in an embedded environment where the normal `new`/`delete` functions are not available, and where a module_id must be used when allocating memory.

The complete code is up for review at: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33858/implementing-create-and-destroy-functions-to-replace-new-and-delete-oper

I have found a problem in the code when multiple inherent classes are used:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <new>

using namespace std;

template<typename T_, typename ...Args>
T_ *create(uint32_t module_id, Args&&... args) {
    // use module_id
    T_ *p = (T_ *)calloc(1, sizeof(T_));
    std::cout << "calloc: " << sizeof(T_) << " -> " << (void *)p << std::endl;
    if (p)
        new (p) T_(forward<Args>(args)...);
    return p;
}

template<typename T_>
void destroy(T_ *t) {
    if (!t)
        return;

    t->~T_();

    std::cout << "free: " << (void *)t << std::endl;
    free(t);
}

struct Foo {
    int i[128];
    virtual ~Foo() { }
};

struct Bar {
    int j[128];
    virtual ~Bar() { }
};

struct MyClass : public Foo, public Bar {
    int k[128];
    virtual ~MyClass() { }
};

#define MODULE_ID 42
int main() {
    MyClass *myclass = create<MyClass>(MODULE_ID);

    Bar *bar = myclass;

    // Error bar != myclass
    destroy(bar);
}
```

**Question: how can this be fixed/workaround? The solution must work on Linux with gcc, and preferable also on Linux with clang**

## UPDATE: based on comments from user396672

I believe that the code below solves my problem, but some details might still be wrong. Also, I would like to avoid using a template argument for parsing the `module_id`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <new>

using namespace std;

template<unsigned ID, typename T>
struct MyObjectWrapper : public T {
    template<typename ...Args>
    MyObjectWrapper(Args&&... args) : T(forward<Args>(args)...) { }

    void* operator new(std::size_t count) {
        void *p = calloc(1, sizeof(MyObjectWrapper<ID, T>));
        std::cout << "calloc: " << ID << " " <<
            sizeof(MyObjectWrapper<ID, T>) << " -> " << (void *)p << std::endl;
        return p;
    }

    void operator delete(void *p) {
        std::cout << "free: " << p << std::endl;
        free(p);
    }
};

template<unsigned ID, typename T_, typename ...Args>
T_ *create(Args&&... args) {
    return static_cast<T_ *>(new MyObjectWrapper<ID, T_>(
                forward<Args>(args)...));
}

template<typename T_>
void destroy(T_ *t) {
    delete /*static_cast<MyObjectWrapper<0, T_> *>*/(t);
}

struct Foo {
    int i[128];
    virtual ~Foo() { }
};

struct Bar {
    int j[128];
    virtual ~Bar() { }
};

struct MyClass : public Foo, public Bar {
    int k[128];
    ~MyClass() { }
};

#define MODULE_ID 42
int main() {
    MyClass *myclass = create<MODULE_ID, MyClass>();

    Bar *bar = myclass;

    // Error bar != myclass
    destroy(bar);
}
```

**Question 1: Is this correct**

**Question 2: can this be done more elegant?**

**Question 3: Can I avoid passing the module_id as a template parameter, it might me use full to allow a variables as module_id**

**Question 4: Do the MyObjectWrapper object need a virtual constructor? I believe that it is not needed**

Comment: There is no error in this code.

Comment: From the man page of free(3) "The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc() or realloc()" The bug is that I call free with the wrong address.

Comment: Why can't you use new and delete?  Can't they be implemented on top of malloc and free, which you do use?

Comment: Remember I need the `module_id` where I call `calloc`, and do not want to create custom `new`/`delete` functions for every class. If this is included in the solution you are thinking of, then I think you should post it.

Comment: dynamic_cast<void*>(pointer_to_base_class) returns a pointer to the most outer inherited class instance (i.e. to the beginning of the allocated memory). So you can use a pointer returned by dynamic_cast<void*> to free the memory.  But you should enable rtti (and make your classes polymorphic, of course)

Comment: And why not to define operator new with additional parameter(uint32 module_id) for some (marker) empty base class?

Comment: @user396672: Are you suggesting to create a class, say: `template<typename T> class ObjectWrapper : public T { ... operator new ... }` which has a local `new` operator, which takes two arguments?

Comment: @user396672: RTTI is not enabled, nor is exceptions so dynamic_cast is not a good idea

Comment: @alan: yes, something like this, but inheritance without crtp should also work (may be I'm wrong?)

Comment: @alan: Anyway, you need virtual destructor for correct deletion of the inherited object via base class pointer, so classes should be polymorphic, even if rtti is not an option (btw dynamic_cast never throws on pointers)

Comment: @alan: More elaborated scketch: struct SpeciallyAllocated{... operator new /*with additional parameter*/...; operator delete /*matching the new, to calm the compiler, will be never invoked w/o exceptions */...;  operator delete /*if special actions needed comparing with standard one */... private: operator new /*with standard signature to prohibit it use*/}... then simply inherit your classes from SpeciallyAllocated. Also don't forget new[] and delete[] if applicable

Comment: @user396672: new[] and delete[] are out-of-scope for now. I do not know the syntax to overload `new` with additional arguments. I will add a post with what I have now, I think this will make the discussion a bit easier.

Comment: @alan: I have converted my sketch into the  answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create a base class containing operator new with additional parameter (module id). Then simply inherit your classes from it

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <new>

using namespace std;

struct SpeciallyAllocated
{
  // operator  new with additional parameter:
  void* operator new(size_t sz, uint32_t mod_id) 
  {
    cout<<" module_id alloacted:"<<mod_id;
        return calloc(1,sz);
  }

  // matching delete (actually is not invoked w/o exceptions):
  void operator delete(void* p,  uint32_t mod_id){}  

  // this one will be usually invoked:
  void operator delete(void* p){cout<<" object deleted"; free(p);}

  private:  // prohibit (for safety reasons) other forms of new-delete operators:

  void* operator new(size_t sz);
  void* operator new[](size_t sz);
  void operator delete[](void* p);
};


struct Foo: public SpeciallyAllocated{
    int i[128];
    virtual ~Foo() { cout<< " Foo destructed";  }
};

struct Bar: public SpeciallyAllocated {
    int j[128];
    virtual ~Bar() {{ cout<< " Bar destructed"; } }
};

struct MyClass : public Foo, public Bar {
    int k[128];
    virtual ~MyClass() { cout<< " MyClass  destructed"; }
};

#define MODULE_ID 42
int main() {
    MyClass *myclass = new(MODULE_ID) MyClass;

    Bar *bar = myclass;

    delete bar;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I see where you are going, but I do not like that the individual objects must be derived from the allocator (many of them exists already and I do not want to change the existing code). But that can easy be avoided by using crtp as I my example. How ever, I was not aware of that `new` could accept additional arguments, thanks for show that.

Comment: @Allan: Ok, you may wrap existing classes: template<typename T>struct Wrapper: public T, public SpeciallyAllocated {} w/o crtp and use wrapped classes

Answer (score 0):

If you can use smart pointers, instead of raw pointers, you could pass a custom deleter.

In this example I used `std::shared_ptr`, but it is easy to change it to `std::unique_ptr`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <new>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template<typename T_>
void destroy(T_ *t) {
    if (!t)
        return;

    t->~T_();

    std::cout << "free: " << (void *)t << std::endl;
    free(t);
}

template<typename T_, typename ...Args>
std::shared_ptr<T_> create(uint32_t module_id, Args&&... args) {
    // use module_id
    T_ *p = (T_ *)calloc(1, sizeof(T_));
    std::cout << "calloc: " << sizeof(T_) << " -> " << (void *)p << std::endl;
    if (p)
        new (p) T_(forward<Args>(args)...);
    return std::shared_ptr<T_>(p,destroy<T_>);
}

struct Foo {
    int i[128];
    virtual ~Foo() { }
};

struct Bar {
    int j[128];
    virtual ~Bar() { }
};

struct MyClass : public Foo, public Bar {
    int k[128];
    virtual ~MyClass() { }
};

#define MODULE_ID 42
int main() {
    auto myclass = create<MyClass>(MODULE_ID);

    Bar *bar = myclass.get();
}
```

---

If this is not allowed, I see nothing wrong with the CRTP wrapper you created.

Answer (score 0):

This might be slightly off-topic, but you might also consider off the shelf components that do exactly what you want to do.

Why implement it yourself and then not keep any interfaces?
All std containers allow you to pass a custom allocator to them. if you want to use stuff as `std::vector` it might come in handy to use the [allocator concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator).

Also boost already provides [Pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/interfaces.html) which allows you to do pool allocation you could possibly use the [singleton pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/interfaces.html#boost_pool.pool.interfaces.interfaces.singleton_pool) and use a fixed size custom allocator. In order to deal with different object sizes normally different pools are used to avoid fragmentation.

There are also memory allocators like [jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/) and [tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) which try to avoid locking and fragmentation by separating allocations by their size, hence looking into that code might be of interest even though using them is not an option.

**About your code**: I think the code works fine, but changes to the interface would greatly improve performance. Furthermore you replaced `malloc` with `calloc` use a separate object like an `allocator` that holds the memory of all of your instances of the same size. ask that object for memory in your overloaded new operators. because you are on an embedded system you should know how much instances your code will expect at a maximum and you should be able to adjust the size of your allocator according to that. you need some way to keep track which objects in your `allocator` are actually in use and which aren't. A bitvector might be sufficient to keep this information. if you can read german scott meyers [slides for embedded C++ (free)](http://aristeia.com/TalkNotes/C++_Embedded_Deutsch.pdf) might be helpful. They're also available in [english (not free)](http://www.artima.com/shop/effective_cpp_in_an_embedded_environment).